# Sequence of passes

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate over a dataframe to found a sequence of passes in football, that precede a shot. What I want is to count the number of passes that ends in a shot. If not, pass. For example pass, pass, pass, shot, pass, pass, shot. If the event is not a pass, skip.

Here we got 2 sequences with a shot, so the final result should be, 3 and 2.

I'm trying to reach it by this way

```
Shot = []
count = 0
for event in events:
    if event == ``pass``:
        count +=1
    elif event == ``shot``:
        Shot.append(count)
        count = 0
print(count)
```

What I'm getting is the number of passes since the beginning till the first shot, and then from that shot till next one.
So I'm getting, for example 233, 456, 129. And w not a real sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to print the shots, rather than the count. This gives me the expected output you described:

```
events = ['pass', 'pass', 'pass', 'shot', 'pass', 'pass', 'shot']

shots = []
count = 0
for event in events:
    if event == 'pass':
        count += 1
    elif event == 'shot':
        shots.append(count)
        count = 0
print(shots)
```

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, don't you want to print the entire Shot list in the last line rather than "count"?

Comment: What i want is to count the number of passes, consecutive passes with no other event, that led to a shot. If final result is shot, count the number of passes that precede that shot. If that sequence of consecutive passes ends, for example, in a foul, pass the count and ignore it. So, i only want the number of passes that ends with a shot.